# Velocity in an aging jelly

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, mathematical-physics

So this might sound like a physics problem, but I am only putting it in physical terms so I can express myself better and make the whole thing clearer.

Suppose I shoot a bullet into a jelly. The deeper the jelly, the thicker it is. But this is a very special type of jelly, which ages very rapidly and so, as the bullet passes through it, the jelly thickens all around in a proportional manner with its density at every point on it.

So, in essence, this problem can be reduced to one dimension.

Now, why I am posting this question in the math section is because I am interested in how to tackle mathematically such an evolving problem. I am quite sure an integral must be used, but I do not see how.

So… to sum it all up:
$v_0$ - initial velocity of the bullet when it first touches the jelly;
$d(x)$ - the density of the jelly depending on its depth;
$a(t)$ - the aging process of the jelly, which depends on time and is applied as: $a(t)*d(x)$.

My question is, in fact, a very simplified version of a charged particle in a magnetic field problem, so this is why I am asking it in a mathematical and general manner, so I can better understand the mathematical mechanism behind it. That is, please to whomever sees this as being interesting, please do not simplify it.

Comment: @Kyky Since a is dimensionless (it is just a scaling function for the density), the units for the expression you gave are (kg/m^3) * (m/s) = kg/(m^2*s) so it would be incorrect.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  If you want to find the velocity of the bullet as a function of time, you'll also need to say how the density affects the velocity.  Presumably, you'd want to use the [drag equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#The_drag_equation), in which case you'd also need to specify how the drag coefficient of the bullet in the jelly varies with depth and time.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Yes, I know my question requires much more details for an exact solution, but why I posted it in the maths section is because I am looking more for an answer like “use the midpoint method in some specific way” or “try integrating something in some way” and not an exact answer for my jelly example.

Comment: So you have asked your question on MSE, because physicists would give you a more precise answer - that doesn't sound like a very sound strategy to me. I think you would do better to ask your question on https://physics.stackexchange.com and come back to MSE if there remain some purely mathematical concerns with the answers you get.

Comment: @RobArthan I see your point. I mean just based on the wave of answers received, this definitely sounds better. But anyhow, for my own use, I realized the midpoint method was the best. However, for a complete mathematical reasoning, I would say an integration analogue to it would be the way to go. So I might come back later with a new question in the PSE, but who knows, I might even find the time to finish this curious jelly question.

Comment: I see. Maybe it would have helped if you'd given a link to the discussion on PSE, so we could see were your were coming from.  Enjoy your jelly!